# Remove blank line before text

Tags: php, line-breaks, strip

Occasionally, my email-to-support-ticket system catches an extra line break before the message itself, thus my messages look like this:

> "
>
> Hello. I have been wondering if y..."

What can I use to get rid of that line before the text? It is on random occasion due to email providers and the way they format their emails using mime.
I have already tried the `trim` functions but no luck. (Yes, I also tried `ltrim`)

Once processed it should look like:

> "Hello. I have been wondering if y..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threw this together, you could rename the function if need be.

```
function removeDeadSpaceBeforeFirstChar($string) {
    $strtemp = $string;

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($strtemp); $i++) {
        if($strtemp[$i] == " ") {
            $strtemp = substr($strtemp, $i, strlen($strtemp)); 
        }

        if($i > 0 && $strtemp[$i] != " ") {
            return $strtemp;
            break;  
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Prints this:

```
      123456789
123456789
```

EDIT: I don't know why I posted the results like that, I was looking over the code and it hit me that I didn't do anything with the substr.. Above is the amended code

Answer (score 4):

it's really strange?

we can use regex here to get only from beginning of a word-character, but's more interesting, to see what's in the string...
can you please post the output of "base64_encode()" of the string, so we can reproduce and take a look into?

here is the regex which should work for you...

```
if (preg_match('/\w.*\w/sm', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Comment: Works too, but his code is a bit less confusing for me. RegEx has never been my thing. Upvote.

Comment: we have to see, what's in the string and why trim() does not work.. trim is *EXACTLY* what you need and will remove any common whitespaces... there must be anything in, what's not standard and we need to know what, to tell you a better solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove arbitrary numbers of carriage returns or newlines from the start of your message body:

```
while (in_array(substr($msgbody, 0, 1), array("\r", "\n")))
    $input = substr($msgbody, 1);
```

If you want to only catch a specific sequence of bytes that occasionally show up at the start of a message (eg, a carriage return followed by a newline), you can use something like this instead:

```
if (substr($msgbody, 0, 2) == "\r\n")
    $input = substr($msgbody, 2);
```

Comment: if you add more characters to the array in the first option you can strip arbitrary types of data from the start, including whatever other characters are tripping up trim or ltrim.